# Retrieve all tablenames containing combination of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to select all tablenames from a database containing a combination of two or more columns: column1 AND column2? 
That is not the right way, I think:

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name = 'column1';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) containing an [`array aggregator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-aggregate.html). The operator `<@` will look for the exact combination of elements.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT table_name, array_agg(column_name::TEXT) AS columns
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  GROUP BY table_name)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE '{column1,column1}' <@ j.columns
```

Example:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT table_name, array_agg(column_name::TEXT) AS columns
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  GROUP BY table_name)
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE '{name,statement}' <@ j.columns;

       table_name       |                              columns                               
------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 pg_prepared_statements | {name,statement,prepare_time,parameter_types,from_sql}
 pg_cursors             | {name,statement,is_holdable,is_binary,is_scrollable,creation_time}
(2 Zeilen)
```